# Wigner distribution

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-analysis

The Wigner distribution of $u\in L^2(\mathbb R)$ is defined as a function $W(u)$ on $\mathbb R^2$ given by 
$$
W(u)(x,\xi)=\int_\mathbb R u\left(x+\tfrac z2\right) \overline{u\left(x-\tfrac z2\right)} e^{-2π i z\xi} \, dz.
$$
It is easy to see that $W(u)$ belongs to $L^2(\mathbb R^2)$ with
$
\Vert W(u)\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb R^2)}=\Vert u\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb R)}^2
$
since $W(u)$ is the partial Fourier transform wrt $z$ of $(x,z)\mapsto u(x+\frac z2)\overline{u(x-\frac z2)}$.

However I believe that for some $u\in L^2(\mathbb R)$, the function $W(u)$ does not belong to 
$L^1(\mathbb R^2)$. Is there an "explicit" $u$ like this?

Comment: I haven't checked all the way through by explicit calculation, but unless I'm missing something, I suspect a box function like $u(t) = 1 $ for $|t|<1$, $u=0$ else, should work, maybe you'd like to check ...

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt You are right, thank you so much. With your $u$, I find $\mathcal W(u)(x,\xi)=H(-x)\frac{\sin(4π(1+x)\xi)}{π \xi}+H(x)\frac{\sin(4π(1-x)\xi)}{π \xi}$ with $H=\mathbf 1_{\mathbb R_+}$ and we find easily that $\int_{\mathbb R^2}\vert\mathcal W\vert dx d\xi=+\infty$. I had in mind a quite complicated abstract argument using the Baire Category Theorem, which I was not able to fully complete.